# Valuation Criterion for Proper Morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Y$ a noetherian scheme and $f: X \to Y$ of ***finite type*** (so ***quasi compact*** and ***locally of finite type***: here the definitions: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T0).

I want to know how to see that following valuation criterion holds:

$f$ is ***proper*** (so  separated, of finite type, and universally closed) if and only if in every diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Spec(F)  @>{a}  >> X   \\
@VViV  @VVfV   \\
Spec(R) @>{t}>> Y 
\end{CD}
$$

for every discrete valuation ring $R$ and $F = Frac(R)$ there exist $l:Spec(R) \to X$ such that $a = l \circ i$ and $t = f \circ l$ holds.

My attepts: I know that $Spec(R) = \{m_R, \eta\} = \{m_R\} \cup Spec(F)$.
Futhermore that because $f$ finite, locally $f$ induces integral ring extension, so the going-up therem for ring morphisms holds.

But I don't see how to use this informations to see the equivalence.

Comment: Do you know the usual valuative criterion using all valuation rings, say from Hartshorne, Thm. II.4.7? Exercise II.4.11 gives a way to prove a valuative criterion involving only DVR's by using the Krull–Akizuki theorem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reference. One point isn't clear to me till now: Krull-Akizuki helps here to reduce the "usual" criterion with valuation rings to DVR's but the proofs didn't explicitely use the ***going up***... or is it implicitely used in K-A?

Comment: I'm a bit confused—how are you proposing to use going up? The morphism $f$ is of finite type, but is usually not integral (since this would imply it is finite, and there are many proper morphisms which are not finite).

Comment: No no, sorry,  I confounded it just with a step in a proof of another theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a precise statement for the valuative criteria you are interested in:

**Theorem** (Valuative criteria for noetherian schemes; see Hartshorne, Exer. II.4.11(*b*))**.** *Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of finite type of noetherian schemes. Consider the following diagram:*
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
  \operatorname{Spec}(K) @>>> X\\
  @ViVV @VVfV\\
  \operatorname{Spec}(R) @>>> Y
\end{CD}\label{eq:star}\tag{$*$}$$
*where $R$ is a DVR, $K$ is the quotient field of $R$, and $i$ is the morphism induced by the inclusion $R \subseteq K$.*

1. *The morphism $f$ is separated if and only if for every diagram of the form $\eqref{eq:star}$, there is at most one morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(R) \to X$ making the diagram commute.*
2. *The morphism $f$ is proper if and only if for every diagram of the form $\eqref{eq:star}$, there exists a unique morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(R) \to X$ making the diagram commute.*

The key commutative-algebraic input is the following:

**Lemma** (Hartshorne, Exer. II.4.11(*a*))**.** *If $(\mathcal{O},\mathfrak{m})$ is a noetherian local domain with quotient field $K$, and if $L$ is a finitely generated field extension of $K$, then there exists a DVR $R$ of $L$ dominating $\mathcal{O}$.*

Now to prove the Theorem, the direction $\Rightarrow$ follows from the usual valuative criteria [Hartshorne, Thms. II.4.3 and II.4.7], and the direction $\Leftarrow$ can be shown by replacing the applications of [Hartshorne, Thm. I.6.1A] in the proofs of [Hartshorne, Thms. II.4.3 and II.4.7] by the Lemma above.

I can give a thorough proof of this if you'd like, but while writing up the proof of the Lemma I realized that Hartshorne's sketch of the argument is fairly complete.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Tibeku [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673692/valuation-criterion-for-proper-morphisms/2678125#comment5972767_2678125), there is something nontrivial that one must check in order to apply the Lemma for the valuative criterion for properness. Namely, one must prove that to check for universal closedness, it suffices to consider a base change $Y' \to Y$ that is of finite type. For this, see [[Görtz–Wedhorn](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-8348-9722-0), Cor. 13.101] or [[Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/), Tags [05JX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JX) and [0205](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0205)].

Comment: Thank you again for to answer. While sketching the proof 4.11(a)+(b) in HS I encoutered still two unclear steps: In (a) it's not clear to me how the field extension $K \subset L$ can be reduced to the case of a finite filed extension. The hint to consider the polynomial ring over $\mathcal{O}$ don't bring me forward. Is it used to separate the trancendental from the algebraic (=finite) part in the extension $K \subset L$?

Comment: And the futher problem regarding part (b): How concretely (b) is aplied to the Theorem? I suppose that by starting with arbitrary valuation ring $V$ (so especially local domain) we find DVR $R$ with properties of (a), which - together with it's fraction field-  can be "attatched" on the left hand side to the commutative diagram as above, then one apply the valuation criterion to $R$ by assumption and show that the added arrow $l$ factorise throught $V$. Or is it the wrong argument?

Comment: @KarlPeter For your first comment, the idea is indeed to factor the field extension $K \subseteq L$ as $$K \subseteq K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r) \subseteq L,$$ where the first is purely transcendental and the second is algebraic. You then replace $\mathcal{O}$ with $\mathcal{O}[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r]_{(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r)}$ to reduce to the case where $K \subseteq L$ is finite, since a DVR $R \subseteq L$ dominating $\mathcal{O}[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r]_{(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r)}$ dominates $\mathcal{O}$ as well.

Comment: @KarlPeter For your second comment, I don't think you can deduce something about all valuation rings from DVR's using (a) of the exercise (it sounds like you want to dominate the valuation ring by a DVR, but I don't think (a) implies this). The proof I have in mind follows the proofs of the direction $\Leftarrow$ in Thms. II.4.3 and II.4.7, but every time Hartshorne says there is a valuation ring dominating a local ring, you can actually assume it is a DVR instead by part (a). This happens twice: in the middle of the second paragraph on p. 99, and the end of the first paragraph on p. 102.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama I am sorry to bother, but I cannot understand, following Hartshorne's proof of valuation criteria for properness, why the valuation ring dominating the local ring could be assumed to be DVR. Since when we check the universal closedness, the base change $Y'\to Y$ is arbitrary, $Y'$ is not assumed to be Noetherian, so the stalk of $Y'$ is not noetherian, thus one cannot expect to find a DVR to dominate it. Could you lend me some help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tibeku There is something nontrivial here: you need to prove that it suffices to consider the case when $Y' \to Y$ is of finite type. See \[[Görtz–Wedhorn](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-8348-9722-0), Cor. 13.101\] or \[Stacks, Tags [05JX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JX) and [0205](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0205)\].